# Automatic formatting for certain words found in Outlook email body

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, formatting

Problem:

We have certain branding formatting for our product names, but manually changing the colour and font style in every email across the company is time consuming.

Solution:

I am trying to build a Macro VBA code to instantly find these words and change the formatting.

The code needs to find a word that starts with the string "abc" and then reformats the entire word to bold and then changes the colour of the "abc" string to the correct brand's colour corresponding to the letters following the full word/product. Once it has been bolded, I don't want clicking the button again to increase the font size, so an "if bolded do nothing" is required

e.g. any word with "abctelephone" needs to be bolded and the abc changed to the corresponding brand's colour. (**abctelephone** with the abc in blue)

I have this scenario working in Word 2013, and I have an example code set below that I have tried to modify from the existing to replicate this functionality in an Outlook email by referencing Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library in the Visual Basic References Tool.

Any pointers?

```
Sub Branding()
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim myObject As Object
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim mySelection As Word.Selection
Dim strItem As String
Dim strGreeting As String  
Dim StrTxt As String, Rng As Range
Dim tempFont As String
Dim tempColour As String
Dim tempBold As String
StrTxt = "abc"         
Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
Set myObject = insp.CurrentItem     
'The active inspector is displaying a mail item.
If myObject.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" And _
    insp.IsWordMail = True Then
    Set msg = insp.CurrentItem
    'Grab the body of the message using a Word Document object.
    Set myDoc = insp.WordEditor
    Set mySelection = myDoc.Application.Selection
    Set hed = msg.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set appWord = hed.Application
    Set appRng = appWord.Selection
    With mySelection.Range
        With mySelection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "<" & StrTxt & "*>"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .Execute
        End With
        Do While .Find.Found
        If .Font.Name <> "Arial" Then
            tempFont = .Duplicate.Font.Name
            tempColour = .Duplicate.Font.Color
            tempBold = .Duplicate.Font.Bold
            With .Duplicate
                .Font.Size = .Font.Size + 2
                .Font.Name = "Zrnic"
                .Font.Bold = True
                If .Text <> "" Then
                    Select Case Split(.Text, StrTxt)(1)
                    Case "telephone"
                        .End = .Start + Len(StrTxt)
                        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 122, 135)
                    Case "handset"
                        .End = .Start + Len(StrTxt)
                        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 122, 135)
                    Case "speaker"
                        .End = .Start + Len(StrTxt)
                        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 122, 135)

                    End Select
                End If    
            End With
        End If
        mySelection.Find.Execute

        Loop
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest calling the Save method of the MailItem class after. Moreover, sometimes you will have to reopen the inspector window if it's opened. Outlook caches old values in the UI and doesn't reflect changes on the fly.

Comment: How do I call the Save method?

Comment: You can find the Save method in Outlook items, for example:     msg.Save()

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would post my final code here that updates the changes on the fly to work in the Outlook draft email.

This could be modified for your own use case.

*Paste into your ThisOutlookSession*

*You need to add the Word Reference library.*

---

```
Function GetCurrentItem() As MailItem
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application

    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
          Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
          Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objeApp = Nothing

End Function


Sub test()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim myInspactor As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim CurrMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set CurrMsg = GetCurrentItem()
    Set myInspector = CurrMsg.GetInspector
    Set doc = myInspector.WordEditor
    ABCBranding doc
End Sub

Sub ABCBranding(doc As Document)
    Dim StrTxt As String, Rng As Range
    Dim tempFont As String
    Dim tempColour As String
    Dim tempBold As String

    StrTxt = "abc"

    With doc.Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "<" & StrTxt & "*>"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .Execute
        End With

        Do While .Find.Found
            If .Font.Name <> "Verdana" Then
                tempFont = .Duplicate.Font.Name
                tempColour = .Duplicate.Font.Color
                tempBold = .Duplicate.Font.Bold

                With .Duplicate
                  .Font.Name = "Arial"
                  .Font.Bold = True

                      Select Case Split(.Text, StrTxt)(1)
                          Case "telephone"
                          .End = .Start + Len(StrTxt)
                          .Font.Color = RGB(0, 222, 111)
                          Case "handset"
                          .End = .Start + Len(StrTxt)
                          .Font.Color = RGB(50, 200, 100)
                          Case "speaker"
                          .End = .Start + Len(StrTxt)
                          .Font.Color = RGB(43, 101, 412)
                    End Select

                End With

            End If
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Find.Execute
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```